# How do I fix segmentation fault guvcview

Tags: segmentation-fault

I have a juision digital 1000x magnification microscope, which I use with my raspberry pi 3b. To use the microscope, you type guvcview into the CMD, however this time it comes up with a segmentation fault (it has worked before). Does anyone know how I can fix this?